# Destroy class member variable in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a class written in typescript, at some point i want to clear the class member variables. How i can do that in typescript.

```
export Class Example{ 
 storeNames: [] = [];
 storeAddress: [] = [];

constructor(){
    this.storeNames = ['mike','nelson'];
    this.storeAddress = ['US','UK'];
}

clearData(){
//here i want to clear those variables, but not in old fashion way,
//I meant assigning them again empty array (this i don't want, because if there are 10 variables then i have to clear them in this method, which is more inefficient way (i feel)
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really any magic here, you just do what you said you don't want to do, assign them new values. The simplest and clearest way to do that is to just do it with the boring old assignments:

```
this.storeNames = [];
this.storesAddress = [];
// ...
```

You could use looping structures and dynamic property name access, but it's less clear:

```
for (const name of ["storeNames", "storeAddress"]) {
    this[name] = [];
}
```

---

Side note: The names of your properties, `storeNames` and `storeAddress`, suggest you're storing data in parallel arrays (`storeNames[0]` is the name of the store at `storeAddress[0]`, etc.). In general, that's not best practice. Instead, store an array of store objects:

```
export class Example {

    stores: Store[] = [];

    constructor() {
        this.stores = [
            new Store("mike", "US"),
            new Store("nelson", "UK")
        ];
    }

    clearData() {
        this.stores = [];
    }

}
```

This also has the advantage of clearing the entire store with a single assignment.